# Apple devices do not pick auto (recommended) subtitle from HLS playlist

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

Apple mobile devices (both of iPad and iPhone) can not choose **auto (recommended)** subtitle from below playlist.

There are 2 subtitles for below playlist and I can see both of them in the list as:

```
Auto (Recommended)
English1
English2
```

When I choose `English1` manually, player can show it. But, when I choose `Auto(Recommended)` subtitle, nothing shows on the screen.

What might be the reason ? Why can't player detect auto subtitle from below playlist ?

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English1",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,LANGUAGE="en",URI="/v2/files/437084058/subtitles/V7mVafQ7LC_B7FKcG3pELRXJ-qBLhSWTC3EG-rZIdtz9z9chtBbbiJPNaaqxv5-W4W_cMmqy3Jj7aAgAsAESJ2r9jzJK9hbwnI7sEBpn1gCZWIUHIcGccvxFis35qhLx2G34Cb0Ql3w%3D/m3u8/3518.688?oauth_token=XXXXXXXX"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English2",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,LANGUAGE="en",URI="/v2/files/437084058/subtitles/V7mVafQ7LC_B7FKcG3pELRXJ-qBLhSWTw0Lzz1oZT8hjlSaW3W54vBgAzgYr65q2T_HyOQqWZfQ-TkSL_bc9bsBXhtqoVjdOGyJBNaVA91_hhS0GwOBh4bebr7QLceQn0MRTag0A8O60r27fNqfrYA%3D%3D/m3u8/3518.688?oauth_token=XXXXXXXX"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1,CODECS="avc1.64001f",RESOLUTION=1920x1074,SUBTITLES="subs",CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
/v2/files/437084058/hls/fragments.m3u8?oauth_token=XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be the AUTOSELECT=NO, DEFAULT=NO
Try to set it to YES, also have a look into the hls spec

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices